# English to Tamil Translator for Windows application

Tags: windows, offline, translation

In my application, I need an English to Tamil Language translator. When the user types in English, I need it to then convert to Tamil language. So I am searching for a translator which can be used for a Windows application (VB.Net in Visual Studio 2008).

I found Google Translator (API), but it needs the internet.  But I need it to work without the internet so can you refer which third party control will achieve this for a Windows application written in VB.Net?

Comment: Microsoft's [translator app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/translator/9wzdncrfj3pg) works offline, but I'm not sure if it supports the Tamil language.

Comment: It is possible to [use the Google Translate app offline](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142473?hl=en), but it currently works on Android only. I hope it will soon be available offline for other operating systems.